# Deploy node js express application - cent os

Tags: node.js, apache, express, nginx, server

I am trying to deploy a node js application on GoDaddy VPS hosting.

I have uploaded all the files to the server and **started** the server using `pm2` 
following [**This Tutorial**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

My server is running on port **`3021`** which I want to run on port **`80`**
for a particular domain.

I have completed steps till `pm2` in the tutorial but from Nginx part, I cannot understand what to do next.

I have installed Nginx then running this command `sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

and adding configurations and when I am saving it an error shows `[ Error writing /etc/nginx/sites-available/default: No such file or directory ]`

I am running apache in the server. Is it possible to do the same using apache??

**Edit**

Here is my nginx config::

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;


include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, it's possible with both nginx and apache. First of all, are you sure that the folder /etc/nginx/sites-available exists? Perhaps it's not part of the centos setup. Also, please post your nginx config and the version `nginx -v`.

Comment: @skovmand if it is possible, then can you please guide me how to do this with apache?

Comment: @skovmand `nginx version: nginx/1.10.2`, this folder `/etc/nginx/sites-available` does not exist at all

Comment: I would just google `apache node reverse proxy` and check out the results. https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+node+reverse+proxy&oq=apache+node+rever&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.8102j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: To your other comment: Create the folder `/etc/nginx/sites-available`  ... That's probably why the original steps failed for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have `pm2` running then you are half way through :) About nginx conf. This command: `sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` probably does not work because the `sites-available` directory does not exist. Keep in mind that `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` are not required by nginx. It's just a good practice to have each server config in a separate file. But nginx will work without them too. If you are not planning to add any more servers, just use the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file to configure your server. What you need to do is to create a new server block with desired configuration, e.x:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  yourapp.com www.yourapp.com;
    root         /var/www/html; # <- for you it can be any other dir
    index        index.html index.htm # <- or any other file which is your main file

    # You want to proxy_pass the traffic on any route to your internal app
    location ~ /(.*) { # ~ means that you are using regex
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3021/$1$is_args$args; # <- proxy_pass to your internal app
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}
```

Just place the above config into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` inside `http` block.

Now check your nginx config:

```
nginx -t
```

If it's successful, your nginx config is done.

It's not over yet. One more thing to do- open port 80 in the firewall, like so:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

You can check if it's open:

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

Open your browser at `http://yourapp.com/` and see if it works.

Remember to keep an eye on nginx and your app's logs:

```
tail -f /var/logs/nginx/access.log # or error.log to see nginx access/error log
pm2 logs # to see your app logs
```

Hope it helps. Do not hesitate to share more info if you encounter any more problems

Comment: And I just realized that this question is pretty old and probably you already found a way to get it working :D

Comment: When I ran `nginx -t` this error shows `nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:81 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)`

Comment: There is apache server is running also

Comment: It seems like ipv6 is disabled on your server. Just get rid of this line: `listen       [::]:80 default_server;` from `nginx.conf` then

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` instead of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to add your configuration. According to your config it should be the correct path to configure your server.

If you want to use `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`you should add `include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;` to your nginx.conf.

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
}
```